# No module rospkg, No module PySide2, No module PyQt5

Tags: ros, rospkg, pyqt, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I installed Ros and am going through the tutorials. It looks like my installation is not correct because when I run the Understanding Ros Topics tutorial and the command:

```
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

I get errors about no `rospkg` module, no `PySide2` modle no `PyQt5` module. I just installed `rospkg` seperately with

```
$pip install rospkg
```

but I cannot get the other two errors to go away. I also don't want to have to install all these modules seperately.
If I try to reinstall Ros full with the commaned:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I get the message:

```
ros-kinetic-desktop-full is already the newest version (1.3.0-0xenial-20170303-123712-0800).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 206 not upgraded.
```

What is the proper way to handle this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256662/no-module-rospkg,-no-module-pyside2,-no-module-pyqt5/) by [stevens1111](https://answers.ros.org/users/29648/stevens1111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-11**:
Btw, please copy-paste the entire log output, instead of explaining by your own words (e.g. saying "no PySide2" provides not enough info). That makes harder for us to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you're on Ubuntu Xenial, so install `rospkg` via `apt-get` as its [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rospkg) instruction says.

---

UPDATE @gvdhoorn

> Shouldn't rospkg and the other modules have been installed automatically during installation of desktop-full?

It should be. So something is wrong with the OP's environment. `rospkg` seems to be depended by some core packages on my Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends python-rospkg
python-rospkg
Reverse Depends:
  ros-indigo-rqt-web
  ros-indigo-rqt-topic
  ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree
  ros-indigo-rqt-shell
  ros-indigo-rqt-service-caller
  ros-indigo-rqt-runtime-monitor
  ros-indigo-rqt-robot-steering
  ros-indigo-rqt-robot-monitor
  ros-indigo-rqt-py-console
  ros-indigo-rqt-publisher
  ros-indigo-rqt-pose-view
  ros-indigo-rqt-plot
  ros-indigo-rqt-msg
  ros-indigo-rqt-logger-level
  ros-indigo-rqt-graph
  ros-indigo-rqt-dep
  ros-indigo-rqt-console
  ros-indigo-rqt-capabilities
  ros-indigo-rqt-bhand
  ros-indigo-rqt-bag
  ros-indigo-roswtf
  ros-indigo-rosunit
  ros-indigo-rospy
  ros-indigo-rosmsg
  ros-indigo-rosmake
  ros-indigo-roslib
  ros-indigo-roslaunch
  ros-indigo-rosgraph
  ros-indigo-rosdoc-lite
  ros-indigo-roscreate
  ros-indigo-rosclean
  ros-indigo-rosbag
  ros-indigo-ros-package-web-server
  ros-indigo-rocon-remocon
  ros-indigo-rocon-qt-teleop
  ros-indigo-rocon-qt-master-info
  ros-indigo-rocon-qt-listener
  ros-indigo-rocon-qt-library
  ros-indigo-rocon-qt-app-manager
  ros-indigo-rocon-python-utils
  ros-indigo-rocon-interactions
  ros-indigo-rocon-hue
  ros-indigo-rocon-gateway-graph
  ros-indigo-rocon-app-utilities
  ros-indigo-rocon-app-manager
  ros-indigo-qt-gui-py-common
  ros-indigo-qt-gui
  ros-indigo-multi-level-map-server
  ros-indigo-lama-interfaces
  ros-indigo-industrial-robot-simulator
  ros-indigo-genjava
  ros-indigo-concert-software-farmer
  ros-indigo-concert-qt-teleop
  ros-indigo-concert-qt-service-info
  ros-indigo-concert-qt-map-annotation
  ros-indigo-concert-qt-make-a-map
  ros-indigo-concert-qt-image-stream
  ros-indigo-concert-conductor-graph
  ros-indigo-concert-admin-app
  ros-indigo-camera-info-manager-py
  python3-rospkg
  python-rospkg-modules
  python-rospkg-modules
  python-rosinstall-generator
  python-rosdep
  python-jenkins-tools
  python-roswtf
  python-roslaunch
  python-roslib
  python-rosdep
$ dpkg -p python-rospkg|grep Ver
Version: 1.1.0-1
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-11**:
Shouldn't `rospkg` and the other modules have been installed automatically during installation of `desktop-full`?

@stevens1111: are you using any alternative Python interpreters by any chance? Like Anaconda? Or do you have multiple versions of Python on your machine? ROS depends on Python2, not 3.